# Access pickatime instance in materializecss and update options

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize, pickadate

I am working on a [materializecss](http://materializecss.com/forms.html) based project. I have some [`pickatime`](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/time/) instances created as follows:

```
$('.timepicker').pickatime({
    default: 'now',         // Set default time: 'now', '1:30AM', '16:30'
    fromnow: 0,             // set default time to * milliseconds from now (using with default = 'now')
    twelvehour: false,      // Use AM/PM or 24-hour format
    donetext: 'OK',         // text for done-button
    cleartext: 'Clear',     // text for clear-button
    canceltext: 'Cancel',   // Text for cancel-button
    autoclose: false,       // automatic close timepicker
    ampmclickable: true,    // make AM PM clickable

    //Function for after opening timepicker
    aftershow: function(){
        console.log(this, arguments)
        console.log(arguments)
    }, 
});
```

Problems:

1. How to access the `picker` instance object? `$('.timepicker').pickatime('picker')` doesn't work - returns the jQuery instance instead.
2. How to update the instance settings after its initialization? For example disable/enable hours or change time format.
3. `aftershow` callback is never called.
4. The first time I click on the `.timepicker` the the timepicker modal opens and immediately closes. Each next click opens the modal as expected.